# Explain why the Hamming distance satisfies the triangle inequality

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

> The Hamming distance satisfies the triangle inequality that is for all $x,y,u$ in $c$ such that $d(x,y) \le d(x,u) + d(u,y)$ where $c$ is a code. Also when does the equality hold?

My approach is: turn $x$ to $u$ by changing at most $d(x,u)$ letters and turn $u$ to $y$ by changing at most $d(u,y)$ letters. So turning $x$ to $t$ will change no more than $d(x,u) + d(u,y)$ letters.

By looking at the following example, $x = 001111, \ y = 111111, \ z = 011111$, the equality holds when changing $x$ to $y$, $z$ is just an intermediate step.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It’s a good intuition, but some work is needed in order to translate it into a proof. For $x\in C$ assume that $x=x_1\ldots x_n$. For $x,y\in C$ let $D(x,y)=\{k:x_k\ne y_k\}$; then by definition $d(x,y)=|D(x,y)|$.

Now suppose that $x,y,z\in C$. Then

$$D(x,y)=D(x,z)\mathrel{\triangle}D(z,y)\subseteq D(x,z)\cup D(z,y)\;,$$

where $\triangle$ denotes the symmetric difference, and therefore

$$d(x,y)=|D(x,y)|\le|D(x,z)\cup D(z,y)|\le|D(x,z)|+|D(z,y)|=d(x,z)+d(z,y)\;.$$

The equality $D(x,y)=D(x,z)\mathrel{\triangle}D(z,y)$ is really just your observation that to get from $x$ to $y$, we can first flip the bits in $D(x,z)$ to get from $x$ to $z$ and then flip the bits in $D(z,y)$ to get from $z$ to $y$. The bits that are affected by at least one stage of this process are those in $D(x,z)\cup D(z,y)$, and those that are affected by both stages are those in $D(x,z)\cap D(z,y)$. Thus $D(x,y)$, the set of bits that are actually changed in going from $x$ to $y$ by way of $z$ are those in

$$\big(D(x,z)\cup D(z,y)\big)\setminus\big(D(x,z)\cap D(z,y)\big)=D(x,z)\mathrel{\triangle}D(z,y)\;.$$

Comment: Could this also be done with a proof by contradiction? 
Assume d(x, y) > d(x, z) + d(z, y), this would mean  D(x,z) ∪ D(z,y) ⊂ D(x,z) △ D(z,y) = D(x, y), which is impossible.

Comment: @DominicNewman: You could organize it as a proof by contradiction, but that just adds unnecessary complexity: once you’ve proved that $D(x,y)=D(x,z)\mathop{\triangle}D(z,y)$, the real work has been done, and you essentially have the direct proof in front of you.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Let $x=(1,2,3,4,5)$, $y=(2,1,4,3,5)$ and $z=(1,2,3,5,4)$, so that $D(x,y)=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $D(x,z)=\{4,5\}$ and $D(y,z)=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. But $D(x,z)\Delta D(z,y)=\{1,2,3,\}\neq D(x,y)$. Am I doing any mistake?

Comment: @user371231: Your calculation is correct, but it has nothing to do with the question: the Hamming distance is a metric on bit strings, i.e., strings of zeroes and ones, not on arbitrary strings. That’s why I talk about flipping bits, not about changing characters.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Since In general Hamming distance is defined in a (linear) code over any finite field, I thought you indicated a proof for the general case. Thanks for your clarification.